# Control event not triggered even though control property is updated from model

Tags: sapui5

I have an input box as you can see in the code below.

The data inside the input box is set using `model#setProperty`, but my `onValueChange` gets triggered only when I enter the value directly into the input box. It's not triggered when the value is manipulated via binding.

```xml
<!-- ... -->
<table:Column xmlns:table="sap.ui.table">
  <Label xmlns="sap.m" text="{i18n>ItemCode}" required="true" />
  <table:template>
    <Input value="{model1>itemCd}" change=".onValueChange" />
  </table:template>
</table:Column>
<!-- ... -->
```

```js
onValueChange: function(oEvent){
  console.log("inside function onValueChange");
},
```

Comment: The `change` event is part of the Input, not of the model. So it is only triggered if you change the actual Input and not the bound value.

Answer (score 1):

As @Marc mentioned `change` event is part of the Input, not of the model. So it is only triggered if you change the actual Input and not the bound value. Its true but there is a workaround for it.

You can achieve it using input [fireLiveChange](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Input/methods/fireLiveChange) event and formatter.

**View.xml**

```
<Input value="{path: 'ipModel>/text', formatter: 'assets.util.Formatter.triggerLiveChange'}" 
       liveChange="ipLiveChange" />
```

**Controller.js**

```
onInit: function() {
    this.setInputModel();
},
setInputModel:function() {
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oModel.setData({ text: "Test Value"});
    this.getView().setModel(oModel, "ipModel");
},
ipLiveChange: function(oEvent) {
    console.log("LiveChange triggered!!");
}
```

**Formatter.js**

```
jQuery.sap.declare("assets.util.Formatter");
assets.util.Formatter = {
    triggerLiveChange: function (value) {
        this.fireLiveChange();
        return (value);
    }
};
```

Comment: liveChange << This is what i was looking

Answer (score 0):

Try with [liveChange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvT9B.png) beacause from library doesn't exist event change, but event liveChange. Perhaps is deprecated?